# [AsynTask][Restful Client(Android user)][Spring framework] ArrayList of Class from doInBackground to onPostExecute

Tags: android, spring

Following is resful web service display on browser.I need to read these data info andoird as client side as list of table

```
ArrayList<PickerItemDetail>
//content of http://127.0.0.1:8080/picking
[
{"pickerBatch":1,"sku":"FL45678976543","name":"Coke 1000L","image":"coke.jpg","qty":"8","pickingStatus":"picked","pickedBy":"John","pickedOn":"02/04/2014","locked":"0"},

{"pickerBatch":2,"sku":"FL45678543675","name":"Mineral Water 50L","image":"drinkingWater.jpg","qty":"5","pickingStatus":"picked","pickedBy":"Roy","pickedOn":"02/04/2014","locked":"0"}
]
```

For android side

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    new HttpRequestTask().execute();
}

private class HttpRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<PickerItemDetail>> {
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<PickerItemDetail> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            final String url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/picking";
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());                
            ArrayList<PickerItemDetail> item = restTemplate.getForObject(url, ArrayList.class);

            return item;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("MainActivity", e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<PickerItemDetail> item) {
        TextView sku = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sku);
        TextView qty = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.qty);
        TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.skuname);
        sku.setText(item.get(0).getSku());
        qty.setText(item.get(0).getQty());
        name.setText(item.get(0).getName());


    }

}

}
```

I would like to read list of data from webservice then display it as a table in android side. 
How do I have a proper code to loop over the ArrayList,I think these code not fully correct way,but no idea to continue/make it pretty works.

```
onPostExecute(ArrayList<>){ item.get(0).getXXX}
```

Hope someone advice
,Thank

Comment: you need to parse the json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly you need but if you want show in listview you can go with 
like this.... in your postexecut=sion 
add this function loadData();

loadDate() function will be like

```
private void loadData() {
            try {
                // looping through All Contacts
                contactList.clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String pickerBatch = c.getString("pickerBatch");
                    String sku = c.getString(sku);


                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put("pickerBatch", pickerBatch);
                    map.put("sku", sku);
                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    contactList.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            ListAdapter adapter = new MySimpleAdapter(Activity.this,
                    contactList, R.layout.list_item, new String[] {
                    pickerBatch, sku }, new int[] {
                    R.id.pickerBatch, R.id.sku });

            setListAdapter(adapter);
            //

            // /
            // selecting single ListView item

        }
```

In this above example contactList is your arrayList... Hope it will work